# jQuery base64 image do not validate in php

Tags: php, jquery, image, base64

In jQuery side I get base64 image by this code

```
$(input).files[0].convertToBase64(function(base64){
    alert(base64); // this code
});
File.prototype.convertToBase64 = function(callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        callback(e.target.result, e.target.error);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this);
};
```

and it is correct

but when I send image to php server , php don't validate image, validate code is

```
public static function check_base64_image($base64) {
        if($base64 === '') return true;
        $img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($base64));
        if (!$img) {
            return false;
        }

        imagepng($img, 'tmp.png');
        $info = getimagesize('tmp.png');

        unlink('tmp.png');

        if ($info[0] > 0 && $info[1] > 0 && $info['mime']) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}
```

what is problem ?

Comment: How are you sending and accepting the data? Is the data even being sent to server? Can you verify what you received the data on the php side?

Comment: i send data with angular $http.post and server side is laravel , i check receive data and use base64 to image converter site and work fine

Comment: Keep in mind that readAsDataURL returns base64 that begins with `data:image/jpeg;base64,` which means that you have to use something like `$data = explode(',', $_POST['data'], 2); echo base64_decode($data[1]);` to get the raw image data.